# Google auto complete on textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want to show all google search auto completes in a textbox.
After searching google i found "http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=test" link that is return a xml data contains ten google search suggets.
My jQuery code for showing this xml values is :

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    $( "#textbox" ).keypress = showSuggest();
});
function showSuggest() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=" + $("#textbox").val(),
        dataType: "xml",
        var data = [];
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('CompleteSuggestion').each(function(){
            data.push($(this).find('suggestion')[0].attr('data'));
        });
        }
    });
    $( "#textbox" ).autocomplete({
        source: data
    });
}
```

jquery-1.9.1.js and jquery-ui-1.10.3 was imported but this code not working.
sorry for my bad english.
thanks.

**UPDATE**

thanks to everyone.
i edit my code and remove xml reading part and replace

```
url: "http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=" + $("#textbox").val()
$("#textbox").autocomplete({
   source: data
});
```

with this :

```
$( "#textbox" ).autocomplete({
source: "http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&q=" + $( "#textbox" ).val()
});
```

now on typing text only show progress image left side of textbox and still not showing suggets.
please help.

**NEW UPDATE**

I write new code with firefox DOMParser but still not working.

```
    $("#textbox").keypress(function() {
    var data = [];
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var xml = parser.parseFromString("http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=" + $("#new-tag-post_tag").val(), "application/xml");
    xml.domain = "google.com";
    suggests = getElementsByTagName("CompleteSuggestion");
    for (var i = 0; i < suggests.length; i++) {
        data.push(suggests[i]);
    }
    $( "#textbox" ).autocomplete({
        source: data
    });
}
```

Comment: This won't work due to the **[Same-origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#textbox" ).keypress(showSuggest);
});                

function showSuggest() {

    // Declare the variable here, not inside the $.ajax code
    var data = [];

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=" + $("#textbox").val(),
        dataType: "xml",            
        success: function (xml) {
            $(xml).find('CompleteSuggestion').each(function () {
                data.push($(this).find('suggestion')[0].attr('data'));                
                 $("#textbox").autocomplete({
                   source: data
                 });
            });


        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your javascript syntax is wrong. This could work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#textbox").on("keypress", showSuggest);
});
function showSuggest() {
    var data = [];
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=" + $("#textbox").val(),
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            console.log(xml);
            $(xml).find('CompleteSuggestion').each(function(){
              data.push($(this).find('suggestion')[0].attr('data'));
            });
            $( "#textbox" ).autocomplete({ source: data});
        }
    });
}
```

anyway I recommend you to learn JavaScript before you start programming.

Comment: What is console.log(xml); do this show xml contains like Console.Write in C#?

Comment: You shouldn't put the WHOLE textbox value in the query, it makes no sense, only the last letters typed, starting from space or a non-letter character.